# MongoDB shell run() function

Tags: mongodb

> run("/test.js")

in mongo shell. i always get error

> run("/test.js")
>   shell: started program /test.js
>   sh2516| Unable to start program /test.js errno:13 Permission denied
>   255

for test i add 777 permission on this file
i doesn't have  any passwords on DB

test.js is empty

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using load() rather than run(). load is for javascript while run is for system binaries.